# View Tomcat's JNDI tree

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, tomcat8

Given I have `context.xml` with `Resource` definitions and I copy it to `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml`

How can I check that `Resource`s were created as expected?

Is there any way how to view JNDI tree after context.xml is applied?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to see what is going on inside Tomcat, you should enable JMX.
See [Monitoring and Managing Tomcat 8.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/monitoring.html).

You can then connect using the `jconsole` command that comes with Java, where you can see the Resources available to each of the webapps running in that Tomcat instance.

I personally never put Data Sources `<Resource>` elements in the `context.xml` file, but instead put them in `server.xml` and then put `<ResourceLink>` elements in the context's XML file (not `.../conf/context.xml`, but `.../conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml`).

This allows multiple webapps running in the same Tomcat instance to share the database connection pool(s).

So in my instance, I can see the Resource Links for my webapp (from `mywebapp.xml`) below the `/Catalina/ResourceLink/Context` node, and the Resources (from `server.xml`) below the `/Catalina/Resource/Global` node.

I can also see the Data Sources below the `/Catalina/DataSource/javax.sql.DataSource` node.

[image]